# MS Word does not show text in EPS created with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ms-word, eps

I created a EPS file with matplotlib 1.4.2 and python 2.7. But when I paste the file in Microsoft Word (Word 2013), it doesn't show the text in the figure. However, when I convert the word doc to PDF file, the text is come back.

I also tried `maplotlib.rcParams` and `matplotlib.use("xxx")` but it can't get it working.

Comment: Your title should be something more or less like "MS Word doesn't show text ..."